# How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

[in here says i need to search 'Startup Disk Creator' and i search but i dont find enything.. what to do?](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

***edit***
OK thanks to you i found the file but now every time i put a 'iso' file it says 0.0B (like its Not weigh any..) what to do now:

Comment: Open the Dash and type "start". The application should appear among the results.

Comment: it doesnt find anything..:<

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: verify the correctness of the iso by md5 first

Comment: what is md5? i dont now anything0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for `usb-creator-gtk`

Answer (score 0):

You can install [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

or you can install the same startup disk creator via

`sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk`

try running it from terminal by `usb-creator-gtk`

Comment: i have 'unetbootin' but it dont reconize my usb stick..

Comment: what about `usb-creator-gtk`?

Comment: you can make bootable usb via simple copy and make usb as active via [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-manage-partition-flags)